# Why is Windows 7 so slow to log-on when my Wireless USB dongle is plugged in?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb

I'm using an Edimax Wireless USB dongle (model EW-7711UTN) on Windows 7 64-bit. The dongle works brilliantly (it was truly plug-and-play) except for one thing.

I've noticed that if the dongle is plugged in whilst I'm logging on to Windows it introduces a massive delay - after I type in my password and hit enter, Windows shows the "Welcome" screen, then the screen goes black for 2 minutes or so (with just the cursor showing) before finally displaying my desktop. If I unplug the dongle before I enter my password, Windows goes straight to my desktop.

Even though the dongle didn't appear to need drivers for Windows 7, I did try downloading the latest ones from the Edimax website, but that made no difference.

Comment: +1 Have seen this same issue with Windows XP systems.  Interetsed if anyone has an answer.  Turning off wireless resolved it every time but not really a fix.

Comment: Is this a personal or work PC?  If it is work, are you on a Domain?

Comment: It's a work PC, but not connected to a Domain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable your system's USB boot capability in your BIOS?

Comment: I haven't tried it - but what's the thinking? The system is well past the boot stage by the time it gets to showing the log-on screen.

Comment: "Come to think of it, when I had this problem on one machine, I used to get as far as a Windows load screen, and in tiny letters it would say "reading I:" or something to that effect. What it was doing was trying to perform some kind of disk check on my iPod. My guess is that could be caused when it's trying to recognize an "unknown" device -- which might be explained by the hub. Plugged in directly, the system recognizes it. With the hub in the way, it doesn't."    http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/275674-31-system-boot